# java.lang.ArrayStoreException: sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy when gradle build

Tags: java

I am using gradle(6.0) to build jar app,but when I start the app:

```
java -jar soa-wallet-service-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

throw error:

```
~/source/dabai/microservice/soa-wallet/soa-wallet-service/build/libs on  master ⌚ 17:10:10
$ java -jar soa-wallet-service-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
2020-01-04 17:12:40.374  INFO 50696 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3328fc2c] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.1.3.RELEASE)

2020-01-04 17:12:41.289 DEBUG 50696 --- [           main] .s.b.ApolloApplicationContextInitializer : Apollo bootstrap config is enabled for context org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@6536e911, started on Thu Jan 01 08:00:00 CST 1970, parent: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@28864e92
2020-01-04 17:12:41.293  INFO 50696 --- [           main] com.sportswin.soa.wallet.AppStarter      : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-01-04 17:12:41.319  INFO 50696 --- [           main] o.s.core.annotation.AnnotationUtils      : Failed to introspect annotations on class com.sportswin.soa.wallet.AppStarter: java.lang.ArrayStoreException: sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy
2020-01-04 17:12:41.334 ERROR 50696 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

java.lang.ArrayStoreException: sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseClassArray(AnnotationParser.java:724) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseArray(AnnotationParser.java:531) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseMemberValue(AnnotationParser.java:355) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotation2(AnnotationParser.java:286) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations2(AnnotationParser.java:120) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations(AnnotationParser.java:72) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at java.lang.Class.createAnnotationData(Class.java:3521) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at java.lang.Class.annotationData(Class.java:3510) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at java.lang.Class.getAnnotations(Class.java:3446) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at org.springframework.core.type.StandardAnnotationMetadata.<init>(StandardAnnotationMetadata.java:70) ~[spring-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AnnotatedGenericBeanDefinition.<init>(AnnotatedGenericBeanDefinition.java:58) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotatedBeanDefinitionReader.doRegisterBean(AnnotatedBeanDefinitionReader.java:216) ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotatedBeanDefinitionReader.registerBean(AnnotatedBeanDefinitionReader.java:145) ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotatedBeanDefinitionReader.register(AnnotatedBeanDefinitionReader.java:135) ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.BeanDefinitionLoader.load(BeanDefinitionLoader.java:158) ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.BeanDefinitionLoader.load(BeanDefinitionLoader.java:135) ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.BeanDefinitionLoader.load(BeanDefinitionLoader.java:127) ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.load(SpringApplication.java:717) [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareContext(SpringApplication.java:392) [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314) [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at com.sportswin.soa.wallet.AppStarter.main(AppStarter.java:32) [classes!/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) [soa-wallet-service-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) [soa-wallet-service-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50) [soa-wallet-service-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51) [soa-wallet-service-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
```

what should I do to fix this problem?I have tried:

```
api "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web-services"
```